# Type-casting int-to-object or scalar-to-array - is there a real use-case?

Tags: php, types, casting

So PHP allows some implicit castings that feel a bit strange, like casting scalar values to objects

```
php > $t = 23;
php > $p = (object)$t;
php > var_dump($p);
php shell code:1:
class stdClass#2 (1) {
  public $scalar =>
  int(23)
}
```

Or the classical pitfall "i forgot count() in an iteration-check":

```
$t = [1, 2, 3];
for ($x = 0; $x < $t; $x++) {
    echo $x . ',';
    if ($x > 5)
        die();
}
```

(which will output `1,2,3,4,5,6` as not `$t` is casted to `int` (which *does* work, its like '0 if empty, otherwise 1'), but instead `$x` is casted to an array with one element.

I'm often asking myself why someone would think that this is a good idea, so i'm wondering: did anyone ever had a real-life use-case where this kind of casting did make sense or was handy/useful?

Comment: Personally i see no use case. Probably it's an attempt to make PHP as robust as possible despite the obvious errors in a code.